# How to archive files and not entire path

Tags: bash, tar

I'm trying to archive specific files on diferent folders. I use this bash command:

```
tar cf file.tar /home/albertserres/Descargas/file
```

Inside the .tar file i have a folder named home inside another folder names albertserres, another folder called Descargas and inside there's my file.

Why this happens? I just need the file, not the entire folder hierachy

Comment: There's no compression going on here. You're just making an archive. And what do Python and TKInter have to do with it?

Comment: Yes i know, but i don't want the folder hierachy inside, I just want the files on the root. I put python and tkinter by error, because the work is about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-C` option to change to the directory before archiving the file.

```
tar cf file.tar -C /home/albertserres/Descargas file
```

In Python this should be:

```
saveFolder = "/home/albertserres/a.tar"
srcFolder = "/home/albertserres/Descargas"
srcFile = "test1"
subprocess.call(["tar", "rvf", saveFolder, "-C", srcFolder, srcFile])
```

Comment: It sends me error: rejected cause going to make empty folder (i translated it from spanish)

Comment: I've tried it and it works for me. Make sure you have a space between the directory and file, not `/`.

Comment: If i do it on a terminal it works with the space! The problem is that i'm using subprocess.call because i'm working on python. Here is the command:

saveFolder = /home/albertseres/a.tar
temporal =/home/albertserres/Descargas/ test1
subprocess.call(["tar","rvf",saveFolder,"-C",temporal])

It dosn't work. error: rejected cause going to make empty folder

Comment: The directory and filename have to be separate arguments to `subprocess.call`. I'll update the answer.